# Typo3 7.6 Flux backend layout column title

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I created a basic template with the builder extension. In the page properties I set `Backend layout` to `fuildpages` and I see now in the backend the 2 columns that the builder extension created:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="standard">
        <!-- Insert fields, sheets, grid, form section objects etc. here, in this flux:form tag -->
    </flux:form>
    <flux:grid>
        <!-- Edit this grid to change the "backend layout" structure -->
        <flux:grid.row>
            <flux:grid.column colPos="0" colspan="3" name="main" />
            <flux:grid.column colPos="1" name="right" />
        </flux:grid.row>
    </flux:grid>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Main">
    <h1>I am a page template!</h1>
    <p>
        My template file is EXT:my_template/Resources/Private/Page/Standard.html.
    </p>
    <div style="float: left; width: 75%;">
        <h2>Content main</h2>
        <v:content.render column="0" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 25%;">
        <h2>Content right</h2>
        <v:content.render column="1" />
    </div>
</f:section>
```

But in the backend this columns don't have the names "main" and "right".

In typo3 6.2 this worked with the basic template the builder create. Do I miss something?

And an additional question: Is there a sysext for the default backend layout `"Left" "Normal" "Right" "Border"`? I wanted to watch there how it is done but I could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `label` attribute on your `<flux:grid.column/>`-tags. The `name` attribute is only used to reference the column in other places, for example to render it using the `<v:content.render/>`-ViewHelper from `EXT:vhs`.

A note on translations of the column label: The `label` attribute can **not** contain usages of the `<f:translate/>`-ViewHelper, due to caching ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidcontent/issues/324)). If you want to translate your column names, you need to provide the translation under some default key, which one that is is explained [here](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/language-usage.html).

Comment: I use the `<v:l />` view helper of vhs extension for the label